# Illegal start of expression for Annotations

Tags: java, ant

I am using Ant to build, I'm getting these errors:

```
Buildfile: ...\build.xml
clean:
  [delete] Deleting directory D:\IdanWorkSpace\ECMSEJB\classes
ejb.compile:
  [mkdir] Created dir: D:\IdanWorkSpace\ECMSEJB\classes
  [javac] Compiling 26 source files to D:\IdanWorkSpace\ECMSEJB\classes
  [javac] ...\src\com\mirs\ecms\mdb\ECMSDispatcherMDB.java:28:   illegal start of expression
  [javac] })
  [javac] ^
  [javac] ...\src\com\mirs\ecms\mdb\ECMSErrorHandlerMDB.java:25: illegal start of expression
  [javac] }
  [javac] ^
  [javac] 2 errors
```

The java class: *ECMSDispatcherMDB.java*

```
@MessageDriven( activationConfig = {
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                            propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                            propertyValue = Constants.CALLS_QUEUE_LOOKUP),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession",
                            propertyValue = "50"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transactionTimeout",
                            propertyValue = "30000"),
} )

public class ECMSDispatcherMDB implements MessageListener
{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ecms.log");
    private static final String TAG = "ECMSDispatcherMdb";
    ConnectorManager connectorManager = ConnectorManager.getInstance();

    @EJB
    private ECMSEntityManagerDaoLocal dao;
    ...
```

The java class: *ECMSErrorHandlerMDB.java*

```
@MessageDriven( activationConfig = {
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                            propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                            propertyValue = Constants.ERORR_QUEUE_LOOKUP),
  @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession",
                            propertyValue = "50"),
} )

public class ECMSErrorHandlerMDB implements MessageListener
{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ecms.log");
    private static final String TAG = "ECMSErrorHandlerMDB";
    ConnectorManager connectorManager = ConnectorManager.getInstance();

    @EJB
    private ECMSEntityManagerDaoLocal dao;
    ...
```

And here's the Ant buildfile *build.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="ECMS Ant" basedir="." default="create ear">
<property file="build.properties" />
<path id="base.path">
    <fileset dir="${project.lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${project.lib2}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">
    <delete dir="${ejb.classes.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${web.classes.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${deploy.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="ejb.compile" description="Compiles the Task" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${ejb.classes.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${ejb.src.dir}" destdir="${ejb.classes.dir}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="base.path" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="web.compile" description="Compiles the Task" depends="ejb.compile">
    <mkdir dir="${web.classes.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${web.src.dir}" destdir="${web.classes.dir}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="base.path" />
            <path refid="${ejb.classes.dir}" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="create jar" description="create jar" depends="ejb.compile">
    <!-- new jars-->
    <jar destfile="${deploy.dir}/ecmsejb.jar">
        <fileset dir="${ejb.classes.dir}">
            <!-- include the folders: facade -->
        </fileset>
        <metainf dir="${ejb.src.dir}/META-INF" >
            <!--exclude name="*application.xml" /-->
        </metainf>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="create war" description="Creates war file" depends="web.compile">
    <war warfile="${deploy.dir}/ecmsweb.war"
        webxml="${web.project.root}/WebRoot/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <webinf dir="${web.project.root}/WebRoot/WEB-INF/" />
        <classes dir="${web.classes.dir}">
            <!-- include the folders: webServices -->
        </classes>
        <classes dir="${web.project.root}/WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes" />
    </war>
    <!--delete dir="${project.root}/WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF" /-->
</target>

<target name="create ear" description="create ear" depends="create war">
    <ear destfile="${deploy.dir}/ecms.ear"
        appxml="${project.root}/META-INF/application.xml">
        <fileset dir="${deploy.dir}" />
        <metainf dir="${project.root}/META-INF" />
    </ear>
</target>
</project>
```

The errors are related to the Annotations I am using.
What do I need to do to fix this Ant build to compile my class Annotations?

Comment: Please post one or more source code snippets relevant to those messages.

Comment: what do you see when you do `javac -version` it's more likely you have Java1.4 or lesser. If you have Java5 or above, change compilation level in ANT to the version of Java that you have.

Comment: I get javac 1.6.0_11, where do you set the compilation level of ANT?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you have trailing commas in your annotation arrays, which javac views as illegal - unlike in 'proper' arrays.  (There is a [bug in eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=284088) that doesn't report these as such.)

Remove the trailing commas, e.g.:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig =
{ @ActivationConfigProperty( ... ),
  @ActivationConfigProperty( ... ),
  @ActivationConfigProperty( ... ),
  @ActivationConfigProperty( ... ) // no comma here
} );
```

Comment: You were right, damn it how could it be true? I am using MyEclipse7.0. it will be annoying now to do it with all the errors of the eclipse compiler

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ant problem *per se*.  Rather, it is most likely a syntax error in one or more of the Java files that you are trying to compile.

If you posted the Java source code, we should be able to be more specific.

---

I don't know what the problem is, but I can tell you for a fact that Ant does not compile Java itself.  Instead, it uses the Java compiler (from the JDK that it finds) to compile the Java.

So if you are getting compilation errors when you compile via Ant, but not when you compile some other way then there is something significant that is different about the way that the Java compiler is being run:

- You might be using a different compiler (from a different JDK).
- You might be causing the compiler to be run with a different build classpath.
- You might be causing the compiler to be run with a different source level.

The second datapoint is the actual errors you are getting.  They are syntax errors rather than semantic errors.  If the problem was the build classpath, then you'd expect semantic errors saying (for instance) that certain annotation names were not known.  Instead, you are getting an syntax error that suggests that the compiler doesn't understands annotations at all.  That suggests that the problem is that the compiler is expecting Java 1.4 (or earlier) code.

So my suggestions are:

- Check that Ant is configured to use a recent JDK.  Check your Ant installation and environment variables as described in the Ant documentation.
- Check that you've correctly set the compiler *source* level in the Ant build.xml file.  Read the Ant documentation for the `<javac>` task, and look at the Sun javac manual entry to make sure that you doing it right.

Comment: I edit my question. although it is compiling fine without ANT.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining a different source level for `javac`?

Since it is recommended to always specify the `source` attribute for the `javac` task, you might have some outdated version specified there.

If your Ant script for example compiles using source level *1.4*, you won't have generics or annotations.

Look for something like this in your `build.xml`:

```
<javac ... source="1.x" ... />
```

**EDIT:** One other way to set the source level for Ant would be using the system property `ant.build.javac.source`, but I doubt that's the case here.

Comment: How could I check/change my source level for javac?

Comment: Normally the source level is taken from the JVM running the Ant script, unless you use the `source` attribute on the `javac` task. (More details: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Comment: I dont have that line in my build xml. i will add my build.xml to the question

Comment: I tried to add source="1.6" to <javac.. still no success.. same error. I have past my build.xml

Answer (score 0):

This strongly points towards Java compilation level, @DR already answered it. Try two things:

1. Download latest ANT, add `$ANT_HOME/bin` it to System Path, where `$ANT_HOME` is the directory where ANT resides (under which bin exists). Remove any reference to any other ANT.
2. Open your build.xml, look the the block where `javac` (compilation) task is added. Make sure it looks like this

   ```
   <target name="ejb.compile" description="Compiles the Task" depends="clean">
   <mkdir dir="${ejb.classes.dir}" />
   <javac 
       srcdir="${ejb.src.dir}" 
       destdir="${ejb.classes.dir}"
       fork="true"
       source="1.6"
       target="1.6">
       <classpath>
           <path refid="base.path" />
       </classpath>
   </javac>
   </target>
        <target name="web.compile" description="Compiles the Task" depends="ejb.compile">
   <mkdir dir="${web.classes.dir}" />
   <javac 
       srcdir="${web.src.dir}" 
       destdir="${web.classes.dir}"
       fork="true"
       source="1.6"
       target="1.6">
       <classpath>
           <path refid="base.path" />
           <path refid="${ejb.classes.dir}" />
       </classpath>
   </javac>
      </target>
   ```